# PETSC header #include'd in a module

Tags: module, include, fortran, petsc

I have a module which holds global variables. To declare some global variables, I need to use HDF5. I am also using a library, so I also need to include a header file. So the preamble of global_variable.F90 looks like this.

```
module global_variables

use HDF5
#include "finclude/petscsys.h"
#include "finclude/petscvec.h"

integer(HID_T) id_file
integer(HID_T) id_plist
Vec M, C, K
...

end module
```

**Vec** is a data type defined in the header file and **HID_T** is a data type defined in HDF5 module.

Now, I have a file which holds subroutines for I/O. This file also uses HDF5 and the same library used in global_variables.F90. So IO.F90 looks like this.

```
module io

use global_varibles

contains

subroutine read_input_file( vector )

Vec vector
integer HDF5err

call H5open_f( HDF5err )
...

end subroutine

end module
```

**Question 1:** compiler returns error when compiling IO.F90, saying that **Vec** is undefined data type. But it does not complain about **HID_T**. I thought global_variables module already contains both HDF5 modules and header files, using global_variables module in IO.F90 will handle every data type declaration but it seems not. Could you please help me understand what I am understanding wrong?

**Question 2:** Is there a way to restrict the effect of #include to the module where it is declared?

PS. If I include `#include "finclude/petscvec.h"` in IO.F90, which declares **Vec**, then it compiles well.

Comment: How is `vec` defined?  Is it a macro, say?

Comment: It is just a C pointer `typedef struct _p_Vec* Vec;`.

Comment: Sorry for my ugly explanation. Library is written in C and it also provides a fortran wrapper. I am using that fortran wrapper as include files. I don't know what exactly is happening inside the header files. It is nested multiple times and finally ends up being `#define Vec PetscFortranAddr`. I don't know what that **PetscFortranAddr** is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax

```
Vec vector
```

is completely alien to Fortran. It works only because Vec is a C pre-processor (CPP) macro defined in the header file *"finclude/petscvec.h"* as

```
#define Vec PetscFortranAddr
```

That means that **you must include the header file in every Fortran file** in which you use the above syntax with `Vec`.  The macro cannot be inherited using the Fortran `use` because it is not a part of Fortran.

The `PetscFortranAddr` is in the end defined in *"finclude/petscdef.h"* as an integer with 4 or 8 bytes depending on your system.

There is probably nothing you can do except reverse engineering what it in the end the pre-processor makes to be, but I wouldn't go that way, it may be unportable.